# regex to find acronyms inside parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to develop a regex to match acronyms inside parentheses.

```
regex = r"\(\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[A-Z]\b\.?\)"
```

This is what I have so far, it works for almost but not all cases. The case where an acronym is on its own line (not preceded or proceeded by any other characters) is also getting matched by this regex even if it is not surrounded by parentheses.

input it should match:
Any acronym in parentheses IE:
`(ADF)`

Input it shouldn't match but it is:
An acronym on it's own line IE:
`ADF`

Any idea what I have done wrong?

Comment: Please give an example of input that it should match and does not (or input that it matches which it shouldn't).

Comment: thanks, added the cases it should match and the case that it is currently matching that it shouldn't @alaniwi

Comment: Are all the acronyms uppercase?

Comment: no they can contain lower case characters which aren't the first or last characters @MarkMoretto

Comment: Yours looks pretty good.  It looks like you have some escaped periods and I'm not sure if those were in consideration.  If you drop the `\b` and `\.`, it should probably work okay.

Comment: The pattern does not match ADF without parenthesis https://regex101.com/r/9jrtwN/1 You could shorten it to `\([A-Z][a-zA-Z.]*[A-Z]\.?\)`

Answer (score 1):

here's what I have so far.  I'm using an "extension notation" to capture the acronym.  The pattern is basically `r"\([A-Z]\w*[A-Z]\)"` otherwise.

```
tst1="this is (ADF) a test"
tst2 = "This is is ADF a test, too."

# Newline tests
tst3 = "\n(ADF)\n"
tst4 = "\nADF\n"

# Upper/lowercase test.    
tst5 = "This is (AdF) a test."
tst6 = "This is (Adf) a test."

def retest(testcase):
    res = re.search(r"(?P<acronym>\([A-Z]\w*[A-Z]\))", testcase)
    if res:
        print(res.group("acronym"))

retest(tst1) # (ADF)
retest(tst2) # None

retest(tst3) # (ADF)
retest(tst4) # None

retest(tst5) # (ADF)
retest(tst6) # None
```